# Is there any relation between resonance and smell of a hydrocarbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, smell

I came across several examples (such as many benzene derivatives) of hydrocarbons having resonance that also seem to have a sharp odour. So, does resonance have an effect on smell?

Comment: Resonance is not a physical phenomenon, it is just a mental picture.

Comment: Aromatic compounds were called aromatic because they have aroma.

Comment: Carcinogenic aroma :-( Salute to the good old organic chemists of the 18th century who risked their lives out of curiosity driven research.

Comment: Then again, many non-aromatic hydrocarbons have aroma as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I could convey the spirit of Professor Louis Fieser on the development of organic chemistry. I couldn't find it in his textbooks, but in class, it went something like this:

Coal distillation led to a large number of different unsaturated compounds, most of which had strong odors, so they were classified as "aromatic". When more quantitative measurements (heats of combustion and heats of hydrogenation) were available, double bonds were investigated, and some compounds were found to be unusually stable. A single $C-C$ bond should have a certain energy, and so would a $C-H$ bond, and so also should a $C=C$ double bond, but some compounds gave surprising results.

Some molecules (like benzene) could be written with two positions for the double bonds - they could "resonate" between the two arrangements. Most of the compounds that had this sort of possibility were odorous (aromatic), so any compound with this sort of resonance possibility was called "aromatic", even if it had no appreciable odor. And they all had some sort of extra stability ("resonance energy") due to the double bond shifting.

Now while "resonance energy" ought to have some quantitative significance, it had some considerable variability, depending on what values you used to calculate the expected value for heat of hydrogenation or combustion. Another term popped into use: "aromaticity", which was never quantitatively defined, but was really a measure of the surprise at the difference between the calculated value and the observed value of the heats.

But I expect that odor is not a result of extra stability, but more likely a result of some reactivity of the multiple double bond system. And volatility.

Answer (score 2):

**There is, but it is somewhat accidental**

Resonance is an odd, ill-defined concept to start with. It was an early attempt to explain the structure and properties of molecules like benzene (which doesn't behave as the entirely hypothetical molecule cyclohexatriene).

The link arises because of the constituents of crude oil. In the early days of chemistry, when experts were trying to understand all the constituents of crude oil they discovered that some distillation fractions contained things with strong, distinct smells (also, as James Gaidis notes, this is true for many products from the distillation of coal). They called them aromatic hydrocarbons. As a better understanding of their structures emerged, it turned out that many of these aromatics contained benzene and its derivatives (toluene, xylene etc.) These were the source of the "aromatic" odours. But their structure posed the above problem noted above: they were clearly unsaturated (ie contained carbon-carbon double bonds) but had distinct properties from simpler alkenes. This led to the idea of resonance (multiple different structures exist in "resonance" where the double bonds move around). Today we would usually talk about delocalised pi-orbitals instead of resonance.

So the group of compounds that led to the idea of resonance happened to be particularly smelly (which is why they were called aromatics). In this sense resonance *is* related to smell. Many volatile benzene derivatives and related compounds happen to have a strong smell. But, more generally, not every molecule with delocalised bonds (or resonance) will be smelly, though it seems very common in simple hydrocarbons.